# Derivative same as the weak derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Are there any conditions under which the derivative almost everywhere is the same as the weak derivative (in the context of the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(U)$)?

Comment: For the qualifier "equal almost everywhere" I see as an example the function $f(x)=|x|$ for which the weak derivative equals the derivative everywhere "except" at zero where the derivative is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

I guess no conditions are required besides the existence of the (strong) derivative and [Edit: it being in $L_{loc}^1(U)$].

Recalling the definition (e.g. book Evans): Let $u,v\in L_{loc}^1(U)$.
$v$ is called the $\alpha$th weak partial derivative of $u$ provided
$$\int_U uD^\alpha\phi dx = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_U v\phi dx$$ for all test functions $\phi \in C_c^\infty(U)$. 
The (strong) derivative satisfies this definition if it exists and provided that it is in $L_{loc}^1(U)$. We conclude since a weak derivative is uniquely defined up to a set of measure zero (see e.g. Evans for a proof).

Edit ctd: the question then remains what if the strong derivative is not in $L_{loc}^1(U)$? Is this even possible? The above integrals are to be understood as Lesbegue integral. Moreover, $\phi$ being in $C_c^\infty(U)$ is of bounded variation. This all makes the above integration by parts formula valid for functions which are not necessarily Riemann integrable. In this sense, I do not know of an example for which the strong derivative exists which fails the above integration by parts formula.

Comment: Why does the classical derivative satisfy the definition? I believe it is not true in general.

Comment: To perform integration by parts, one uses the fundamental theorem of calculus. Then continuity of the derivative (or at least Riemann integrability) is needed. This is a non-trivial additional assumption; see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks for pointing this out. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz actually, the derivative of the Volterra function is integrable in Lesbegue sense. So the integration by parts formula should not be a problem.

Comment: You're right, everything's OK in Lebesgue sense. Since $f'$ exists everywhere and is bounded, $f$ is Lipschitz and the fundamental theorem of calculus holds. Although I couldn't find a similar reasoning for $f'$ defined everywhere with $f' \in L^1_{loc}$). Does it follow that $f$ is absolutely continuous?